# Buscador en angular 11 con pipe filter

Tags: angular, typescript, filtro, pipe

Hola Tengo un buscador en angular 11 con pipe filter  Me filtra por un campo pero como haría para filtra mas de un campo desde un input como por ejemplo ver si hay un usuario con el  nombre y apellido

```
const resultado = [];



for (let valor of objeto) {

  if (valor.cedula.indexOf(input)  > -1) {
    resultado.push(valor);
    }

  





}
return resultado;
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la estructura del JSON que quieres filtrar?

Comment: el ítem del nombre y el apellido que están en dos campos diferentes por ejemplo ... Nombre Apellido y me filtre ese usuario  !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede que te sirva lo siguiente, un filtro personalizado para tu objeto.

Suponiendo que tu objeto es algo como el siguiente:

```json
 items = [
    {
      nombre: "Pedro",
      apellido: "Ramirez",
      edad: 28
    },
    {
      nombre: "Juan",
      apellido: "Hernandez",
      edad: 22
    }
  ];
```

Hacemos un pipe personalizado:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({ name: "customFilter" })
export class CustomFilter implements PipeTransform {
  transform(mObjects: { apellido: string; nombre: string }[], input: string) {
    if (!input) return mObjects;
    return mObjects.filter(val => this.filterBy(val, input));
  }

  private filterBy(
    mObject: { apellido: string; nombre: string },
    search: string
  ) {
    const reduced = Object.keys(mObject)
      .reduce((prev, current) => this.reduceKeys(prev, current, mObject), "")
      .toLocaleLowerCase();
    return reduced.indexOf(search.toLocaleLowerCase()) > -1;
  }

  private reduceKeys(
    prev: string,
    current: string,
    mObject: { apellido: string; nombre: string }
  ): string {
    if (this.isProp(current)) {
      prev = `${prev}\$${mObject[current]}`;
    }
    return prev;
  }

  //Aquí validas que propiedades quieres que se filtren.
  private isProp(key: string): boolean {
    return key.includes("apellido") || key.includes("nombre");
  }
}
```

Lo puedes probar de la siguiente manera:

```html
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="search" />

<li *ngFor="let item of items | customFilter: search">
    {{item | json}}
</li>
```