# pipe filtrar 2 campos

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic, pipe

Hola comunidad !

Tengo un problema con los pipe en ionic al querer filtrar más de un campo mediante un input:

Este es mi pipe:

```js
import {​​
  Pipe,
  PipeTransform
}​​ from '@angular/core';



@Pipe({​​

  name: 'usuario'

}​​)

export class UsuarioPipe implements PipeTransform {​​



  transform(arreglo: any[], texto: string = '', columna: string = 'nombre'): any[] {​​



    console.log(arreglo);

    console.log(texto)



    texto = texto.toLocaleLowerCase()



    return arreglo.filter(item => item[columna].toLowerCase().includes(texto))



  }​​







}​​
```

y mando a llamar a mi pipe de la siguiente manera

```html
<ion-card class="card-inclompleta" *ngFor="let user of usuariosApp | usuario:BuscarUser:'nombre' && 'email'">



  <ion-card-header>

    <ion-card-title>{​​{​​user.nombre}​​}​​</ion-card-title>

    <ion-card-subtitle>{​​{​​user.email}​​}​​</ion-card-subtitle>

    <ion-card-subtitle>{​​{​​user.telefono}​​}​​</ion-card-subtitle>

  </ion-card-header>



</ion-card>
```

Tengo una lista de usuarios y quiero filtrarlos por medio del nombre, correo y numero, pero al llamar mi pipe solo me respeta un campo y no los dos (nombre, email y de preferencia número)

De antemano gracias.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Es por que tienes que enviar un arreglo. Para enviar múltiples parámetros a tu `@Pipe` es necesario usar `:`.

```html
<ion-card class="card-inclompleta" 
 *ngFor="let user of usuariosApp | usuario:'BuscarUser':'nombre':'email'">
```

Para recibir esos parametros utiliza un [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/parametros_rest) `...args:[]`.

```
 transform(arreglo: any[], ...entradas: any[]): any[] {​​
  console.log(entradas[0]); // BuscarUser
  console.log(entradas[1]); //nombre
  console.log(entradas[2]); //email
 }
```

Comment: Hola Oscar, gracias por contestar, intenté hacerlo así pero no logro filtrar el nombre y el email, es decir, me busca tal cual las palabras de los campos pero no el texto que pongo en el input, ¿sabes como puedo filtrar las entradas em el pipe?

Comment: @carlosGRJ revisa [esta otra respuesta para que la complementes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/421502/buscador-en-angular-11-con-pipe-filter/421900#421900)